# Python NLTK: How to find similarity between user input and excel data

Tags: python, nltk

So I'm trying to create an python chatbot, I have an excel file with hundreds of rows which looks like below:

```
QuestionID     Question               Answer        Document 
Q1             Where is London?       In the UK     Google
Q2             How many football      22            Google
               players on the pitch?
```

Now when the user inputs a question, such as "Where is London?" or "Where is London" I want it to return all the text in that row.

I can successfully print what is in the excel file, but I'm not sure how to go through all the rows and find the row which is similar or matches the users question.

```
text = []
    
with open("dataset.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        text.append((row['Question'], row['Answer'], row['Document'] ))
    
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas

```
`import pandas as pd 

# loading data into pandas DataFrame from file
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

# given question
question = "How many football players on the pitch?"

# df.loc[(condition)] gives you all the rows that satisfy your condition
# in this case the questions have to match entirely. 
rows_with_similiar_question = df.loc[df["Question"] == question]

# prints the first answere
print(rows_with_similiar_question['Answer'].values[0])`
```

More on pandas and dataframes [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably wouldn't want to do an exact match, since that means it will be case sensitive, and need exact punctuation, no misspellings, etc.

I would look at using `fuzzywuzzy` to find a match score. Then you can return the solution that best matches the question:

**Example:**

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd

lookup_table = pd.DataFrame({
        'QuestionID':['Q1','Q2','Q3'],
        'Question':['Where is London?','Where is Rome?', 'How many football players on the pitch?'],
        'Answer':['In the UK','In Italy', 22],
        'Document':['Google','Google','Google']})



question = 'how many players on a football pitch?'

lookup_table['score'] = lookup_table.apply(lambda x : fuzz.ratio(x.Question, question), axis=1)
lookup_table = lookup_table.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
```

**The result table:**

```
print (lookup_table.to_string())

  QuestionID                                 Question     Answer Document  score
2         Q3  How many football players on the pitch?         22   Google     71
0         Q1                         Where is London?  In the UK   Google     34
1         Q2                           Where is Rome?   In Italy   Google     27
```

**Give the answer to the top choice:**

```
print (lookup_table.iloc[0]['Answer'])
22
```

or since you want the row

```
print (lookup_table.head(1))
  QuestionID                                 Question Answer Document  score
2         Q3  How many football players on the pitch?     22   Google     71
```